# Regex Pattern for Ascii Tree Parsing (Maven/Gradle Dependency output)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I am attempting to build a comprehensive regex pattern to match all the an ascii tree , which is an outcome of mvn/gradle dependency representation

Note that the pattern should address the following order options

```
+- 
|    +---
|    |    +---
|    |    \---
\---
     \---
```

This regex pattern matches but does not take ordering into consideration. Would appreciate some advice in this matter

```
(\|)|(\\-*)|(\+-*)
```

A sample data file is specified below

```
+- com.acme.org:commons-integration:jar:2.39.0:compile
|  +- (com.acme.org:commons-core:jar:2.39.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
|  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
|  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
|  +- (org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.5:compile
|     +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
|     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
+- active project artifact:
    artifact = com.acme.org:foo-core-impl:jar:1.0.41-SNAPSHOT:compile;
    project: MavenProject: com.acme.org:foo-core-impl:1.0.41-SNAPSHOT @ /opt/jenkins/home/jobs/foo/workspace/trunk/foo-core-impl/pom.xml
|  +- active project artifact:
    artifact = com.acme.org:foo-core:jar:1.0.41-SNAPSHOT:compile;
    project: MavenProject: com.acme.org:foo-core:1.0.41-SNAPSHOT @ /opt/jenkins/home/jobs/foo/workspace/trunk/foo-core/pom.xml
|  |  \- (com.acme.org:commons-core:jar:2.39.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (com.acme.org:commons-core:jar:2.39.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- com.acme.org:referentials-client:jar:2.11.11:compile
|     +- com.acme.org:referentials-core:jar:2.11.10:compile
|     |  +- (com.acme.org:commons-client:jar:2.40.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     \- (com.acme.org:commons-client:jar:2.40.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.39.0)
+- com.acme.org:commons-core:jar:2.39.0:compile
|  +- commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
|  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile (version managed from 2.0)
|  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
|  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.3:compile (version managed from 2.1.3)
|  |  +- (javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile - version managed from 2.0; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.8:compile
|  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
|  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
|  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
|  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
|  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
|  |  \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
|  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.9.1)
|  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |  +- (junit:junit:jar:4.4:compile - version managed from 3.8.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
|  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4)
|  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
|  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
|  |  |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
|  |  +- com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1:compile
|  |  \- com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1:compile
|  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
|  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
|  \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.0.5:compile
|     +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|     |  \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|     \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|        +- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|        \- (org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
|  +- (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
+- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
+- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
+- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
+- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
|  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
|  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
|  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4:compile
|  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
|  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.6:compile
|  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
|  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
|  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.5)
|  \- stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
+- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- (stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
+- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
+- com.acme.org:commons-client:jar:2.39.0:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
|  +- (com.acme.org:commons-core:jar:2.39.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:runtime
|  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.1.0:runtime
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:1.3.0:runtime
|  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
|  |  |  +- (javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:runtime - version managed from 2.0; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.3:runtime - version managed from 2.1.3; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:runtime
|  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec:jar:1.0:runtime
|  +- org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.0:runtime
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
|  |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:2.1:runtime
|  +- com.ibm:mqjms:jar:6.0.0:runtime
|  +- com.ibm:mq:jar:6.0.0:runtime
|  +- com.ibm:connector:jar:6.0.0:runtime
|  +- com.ibm:jta:jar:6.0.0:runtime
|  \- com.ibm:dhbcore:jar:6.0.0:runtime
+- com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.1.0:runtime
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:runtime
|  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
+- com.acme.org:commons-test:jar:2.26.8:test
|  +- httpunit:httpunit:jar:1.7:test
|  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:test
|  |  \- jtidy:jtidy:jar:4aug2000r7-dev:test
|  +- (org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:test
|  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (junit:junit:jar:4.4:test - version managed from 3.8.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.24:test
|  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.24:test
|  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:test
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:test
|  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:test - version managed from 2.2.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.3:test - version managed from 2.2.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
+- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.7:test
|  +- (org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.4.7:test
|     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.4.7:test
|     |  +- (org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.4.7:test - omitted for duplicate)
|     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.14.0-GA:test
|     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.4.7:test
|        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
\- junit:junit:jar:4.4:test (scope not updated to compile)


+- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.190:compile
+- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
|  \- axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:runtime
+- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
+- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
+- org.apache.axis:axis-ant:jar:1.4:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
+- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
+- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
+- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
|  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
+- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
+- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
+- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.5:compile
+- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.4:compile
+- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:compile
+- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
+- java2html:j2h:jar:1.3.1:compile
+- ecs:ecs:jar:1.4.2:compile
+- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
+- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1:compile
+- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:jar:7.0.65:provided


+--- project :hollow
\--- project :hollow-ui-tools
     +--- project :hollow
     +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7
     |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
     |    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4
     +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.3
     \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
^ *((\| +)*\+-+|(\| +)*\\-+)
```

I match the start of a line followed by zero or more spaces then the pipe with trailing spaces zero or many times followed by a plus and a dash one or many times OR a pipe with trailing spaces zero or many times followed by a backlash and a dash one or many times.

That covers all the patterns I can see in both your test case and your actual maven output.

Comment: Thanks Matt. However these patterns are always prefixed to a line.
It fails to match when I apply a start of line anchor 

`^((\| +)*\+-+|(\| +)*\\-+)`

Comment: No problem. I've edited the regex to include a start of line anchor followed by zero or more spaces.

Comment: You need to turn on the `m` flag to match the start of line anchor `^` on multiple lines i.e. `/^ *((\| +)*\+-+|(\| +)*\\-+)/gm`. How are you going to run this regex in practise?

Comment: It's not multi line . I am planning to eval the expression on a per line basis

Comment: Yep that's fine. It's just on the regexr page that you need the flag on so that it evaluates each line correctly. If you use the regex in PHP or Java or whatever, and you read the text line by line, you won't need any flags.